# Compile Android application with gradle

Tags: android

I have a continuous integration library to compile android applications with `nodejs` and `gradle` from commits on Git server.

I'm trying to install on RPI, but I can't.  I need the Android SDK but when I try to install I get this error:

```
 pi@raspberrypi ~/android/android-sdk-linux $   tools/android update sdk --no-ui

    SWT folder '/home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/arm' does not exist.
    Please export ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platform.
```

Can I install the SDK components only for compile correctly or this is impossible?

Comment: Have you installed Java? IIRC one cannot assume that Raspian has Java installed by default.

Comment: do you already have a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

There is no ARM version of the tools provided by Google.

A few people started working on the build tools though, but not the platform tools.

https://github.com/skyleecm/android-build-tools-for-arm

I gave it up by now and see myself forced to build on another machine.